# How to restrict payment and shipping method based on category id [Opencart 2x]

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I need some solution to hide/show specific payment and shipping methods based on category id of the products in the shopping cart.

Any suggestions would help. Thanks in advance!
Opencart version: 2.1.0.2

Comment: the `use-case` you're referring will have to be `developed` using `vQmod` or `OCMOD`. There is no such in-built setting to do so in `opencart`

Comment: No problem. I'm familiar with vqmod. Just wondering what should be done to have this.

Comment: Let's assume for instance you've products with same `category_id` in the `cart`, then its a pretty straight forward `logic`. Just set an additional variable in `session` & check it on `cart` module & then you can show/hide payment & shipping methods as per your logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to restrict payment and shipping method based on product's weight:

http://aaviya.com/opencart-restrict-payment-and-shipping-methods-based-on-products-weight/